# Question on the proof of the Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics

In Nielsen and Chuang's book on quantum computing, the following proof for the spectral theorem (any normal matrix is diagonalizable with unitary matrices) is given.

[image: Proof]

I'm unable to follow the statement that QMQ is diagonalizable by an orthogonal basis for the space Q by induction. To me, QMQ is an operator going from V to V, so it being diagonalizable with unitary matrices relies on assuming that a normal matrix in V is diagonalizable with unitary matrices, but the induction hypothesis only suggests this for subspaces with a smaller dimension than V.

Any clarification would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is deserving of some clarification. We can find an orthonormal basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ for $V$ such that $v_1, \dots, v_k$ is a basis for $P$ and $v_{k+1}, \dots, v_n$ is a basis for $Q$. Now, lets look at the matrices $PMP$ and $QMQ$ in these bases. We have $v_i$ is an eigenvector $PMP$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ for $i=1, \dots, k$ and in the kernel of $PMP$ for $i = k+1, \dots, n$. Thus, $P$ has the block diagonal form $$ PMP = \begin{pmatrix} \Lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ where $\Lambda$ is the $k\times k$ matrix $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda, \dots, \lambda)$. This is what they meant by

> $PMP$ is already in diagonal with respect to some orthonormal basis $P$.

Now, for $QMQ$, we know that $v_i$ is in the kernel for $i = k+1, \dots, n$, and the image of $QMQ$ is contained in the subspace $Q$, so we may write $$QMQ = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix}$$ for some $(n - k) \times (n-k)$ matrix $A$. Now, $QMQ$ being normal implies $A$ is normal, so there is an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B = \{w_{k+1}, \dots, w_{n}\}$ for $Q \cong \mathbb C^{n-k}$ such that $A$ is diagonal. If $B : \mathbb C^{n-k} \to \mathbb C^{n-k}$ is the change of basis matrix from our old basis to $\mathcal B$ then $BAB^{-1}$ is diagonal, the basis $v_1, \dots, v_k, w_{k+1}, \dots, w_n$ is orthonormal, and the matrix
$$C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} $$ is our desired change of basis matrix. In other words,
$$CMC^{-1} = CPMPC^{-1} + CQMQC^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} \Lambda & 0 \\ 0 & BAB^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the Nielsen and Chuang text is not clear.

$QMQ |v\rangle = QM |v_Q\rangle  = Q\lambda |v_Q\rangle = \lambda |v_Q\rangle$

$\Rightarrow dim(QMQ) < dim(M)$

Hence, if $QMQ$ is normal,  then $QMQ$ is diagonalizable (induction hypothesis on dimension).

Comment: The right angle bracket $\rangle$ can be obtained using `\rangle`.

Comment: I have corrected it. Thanks!